# Excel logic AND and OR functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Does my formula below need to read `(Occupancy=1)*(Gender=2)` to consider the occupancy for both genders?

```
=(MIN(IF((Occupancy=1)*(Gender=1)+(Gender=2),Gross_Rev)))
```

I guess as a general question, does the `AND` function have to be paired with each `OR` function? The logical relation I am trying to represent is `Cond1 AND (Cond2 OR Cond3)`.

Comment: What exactly is your logic, is it `Cond1 AND (Cond2 OR Cond3)`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am after. would it be (Cond1)*((Cond2)+(Cond3))?

Comment: It is unclear to which logic you are trying to achieve. Can you please clarify in your question?

Comment: Are you trying to perform math using order of operations or logic? You state you want AND and OR but you keep showing multiplication and adding.

Comment: @EricF, its boolean arithmetic, see [http://support.microsoft.com/KB/267982](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/267982)

Comment: My mistake. I guess I learned something new

Comment: Either your example is misleading, or you’re making things more complicated than you need to. In the real world, `(Gender=1) OR (Gender=2)` generally equates to ***all***, so your expression can collapse to `=MIN(IF(Occupancy=1, Gross_Rev))`. Even if you are dealing with Cond2 and Cond3 that do not cover the entire space, e.g., `=MIN(IF((Occupancy=1)*((Eye_color=1)+(Eye_color=2)), Gross_Rev))`, you don’t need the outer parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, since you want the logic to be `Cond1 AND (Cond2 OR Cond3)`, you need to introduce two braces to group the OR conditions and then apply AND to it.

```
=(MIN(IF((Occupancy=1)*((Gender=1)+(Gender=2)),Gross_Rev)))
```